# How to apply scopes to association through collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model `Category` that `has_many :posts`.
On my index page I iterate over categories and output it something like this:

```
@categories.each do |category|
  link_to category.title, category

  category.posts.published.limit(4).each do |post|
    link_to post.title, post
  end

end
```

It works, but `published.limit(4)` doesn't belong there and I'd like to move it to the controller. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I think you're taking this a bit too far. Showing only N items in a view seems like presentation logic to me, not business logic and as such is appropriate for a view.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the comment. Maybe you're right. But I itentionally simplified the example code. Besides, I like to keep things organized, and my controller sets up several diffenet instance variables. And if I decide to change this logic, they will all be in the controller so I won't need to go through hundreds of rows in my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a scope on Post that encapsulated both published and a limit:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :highlights, published.limit(4)

end
```

And then use it in the view like so:

```
@categories.each do |category|
  link_to category.title, category

  category.posts.highlights.each do |post|
    link_to post.title, post
  end
end
```

If you wanted to be able to customize the length of the highlights you could change the scope call to look like this:

```
scope :highlights lambda { |size| { published.limit(size) } }
```

and then use it like:

```
category.posts.highlights(5)
```

Comment: I think it's not better than my current implementation, because the logic stays in the view - that's what I'm trying to change.

Comment: The only part here that's in the view is `category.posts.highlights`, if the limit is in the scope. If you choose to use the lamba approach for the limit, you can set an instance var in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an object in controller like:

```
def index
  @published_posts = @categories.collect { |c| c.posts.published.limit(4) }
  # but this will be an array of arrays, so let flatten
  @published_posts = @published_posts.flatten # array of published posts
end
```

now you can use this variable in your views.

Comment: Won't work for me, I guess. I still need to do `categories.each` (to outup it's title and link) and then print it's posts.

Comment: ok, collect not only categories but their titles, for example using a hash 
`@categories.collect { |c| { :title => c.title, :posts => c.posts.published.limit(4) } }`
so as a result you'll have an array of hashes with all information you need ;)

Comment: Ok, but what if there were more fields in the category, i'd like to include? Actually, I think, I've found a solution and will update my question shortly. I don't like it very much too, but this way my views stay more consistent.